# Tomcat 2 service parallel run

Tags: tomcat

I am trying to run simultaneously 2 different instances of Tomcat on the same machine.
So far I have done the following:

1. Copied initial Tomcat folder to another path. So now I have Tomcat at /opt/tomcat and Tomcat2 at /var/lib/tomcat2
2. Edited /tomcat2/conf/server.xml to point on different ports. Specifically:

   > server port="8105"
   > Connector port="8090"
   > Connector port="8109"
3. Created /etc/init.d/tomcat2 with the following settings:

   [Unit]
   Description=Tomcat 8.5 servlet container
   After=network.target

   [Service]
   Type=forking

   User=tomcat
   Group=tomcat

   Environment="JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java"
   Environment="JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/urandom"

   Environment="CATALINA_BASE=/var/lib/tomcat2/latest"
   Environment="CATALINA_HOME=/var/lib/tomcat2/latest"
   Environment="CATALINA_PID=/var/lib/tomcat2/latest/temp/tomcat2.pid"
   Environment="CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms512M -Xmx1024M -server -XX:+UseParallelGC"

   ExecStart=/var/lib/tomcat2/latest/bin/startup.sh
   ExecStop=/var/lib/tomcat2/latest/bin/shutdown.sh

   [Install]
   WantedBy=multi-user.target

I then `systemctl daemon-reload`
So far I can individually run either of the 2 services, but I can't run them in parallel.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Why?  What is in the logs in the failing server?

Comment: While tomcat2 is running I am trying to run tomcat:
Jun 27 11:01:25 systemd[1]: tomcat.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 27 11:01:25 systemd[1]: Failed to start Tomcat 8.5 servlet container.

Comment: But what to the Tomcat logs say?